# PowerShell Snippet Not Replacing All Characters

Tags: powershell, code-snippets

I have a PowerShell script that for the life of me does not seem to want to work completely. I am converting log files from `Tab Delimited` to `CSV` and removing a special character `=` to prevent undesired hiccups when opening the file in Excel. Here is my code, and while looking at other examples on StackOverflow it seems to be consistent. I can't figure it out.

```
foreach( $DecodedFile in (Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\rybrow\Desktop\Picnic Data\' -Recurse -Filter "*.decoded.txt" -File) ) {
    $path = $DecodedFile.FullName # "C:\fso\tabDelimited.txt"
    $outPath = $path -replace ".txt",".csv"
    Get-Content -path $path | ForEach-Object {
    '"' + ($_ -replace '=', '' `
    -replace '\t','","') + '"' `
    } |  Out-File -filepath $outPath -Encoding Ascii
}
```

Thanks for taking a look and helping me out!

```
[2014-07-01 08:00:17.724]   -ACCESS ACCEPTED    -(hash function took 11.1953 ms, lookup took 0.0041 ms) -1000:cmFmdkcyRVBsdWJyaXVzVW51cTwxNzc2:RPR4hRivNC0GgQWCcv0gWPkhB90= -CARD Number OK 1234567890          CLASS   VERSION VISITOR (no photo)  unused (System)
```

Comment: Can you provide a line that is not properly being replaced?

Comment: I added a line from the code, and when doing so I think I found the problem. The `=` signs are not in the file, they are created by Excel. Aggravating! I believe the `-` symbols are instigating it though.

Comment: How is the output not being translated? Are tabs not getting replaced? Badly formatted?

Comment: Did you get it to work after accounting for the hyphens?

Comment: I figured out the issue. Excel saw any field beginning with a `-` followed with a capitalized word as an attempt at a formula. It added the character in at that point so I just wrote a `-replace` for the `"-`  with `"` after I completed the removal of the tab delimiter to ensure that I didn't screw up the date format in field 1. Thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think some brackets would solve your problem:

```
foreach( $DecodedFile in (Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\rybrow\Desktop\Picnic Data\' -Recurse -Filter "*.decoded.txt" -File) ) {
    $path = $DecodedFile.FullName
    $outPath = $path -replace ".txt",".csv"

    Get-Content -path $path | ForEach-Object {
      '"' + (($_ -replace '=', '')  -replace '\t','","') + '"'
    } |  Out-File -filepath $outPath -Encoding Ascii
}
```

You code was replacing all the tabs in an empty string, A more robust way to do it so you don't have to worry about replacing double quotes would be to use Export-Csv like so:

```
foreach( $DecodedFile in (Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\rybrow\Desktop\Picnic Data\' -Recurse -Filter "*.decoded.txt" -File) ) {
    $path = $DecodedFile.FullName
    $outPath = $path -replace ".txt",".csv"

    $csv = Import-Csv $path -Delimiter "`t"
    $csv_cols = $csv | gm -MemberType NoteProperty | Select name -ExpandProperty Name

    $csv | % {
      $row = $_
      $csv_cols | % {
        $row."$_" = $row."$_" -replace '=', ''
      }
    } | Export-Csv $outPath -Encoding Ascii 
}
```